# Integral of Brownian motion divided by time

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

So, I'm battling with two problems:

Show that:

1. $$ \int_0^1 \frac{B_s}{s} ds $$ is finite
2. $$ B_t - \int_0^t \frac{B_s}{s} ds $$ is Brownian Motion

My attempt was to start with:
$$ d(B_t \ln t) = \ln (t) dB_t + \frac{B_t}{t} dt $$.

Then we can write:
$$ B_1 \ln(1) - B_0 \ln(0) = \int_0^1 \ln(s) dB_s + \int_0^1 \frac{B_s}{s} ds$$

Left handside is equal to zero, assuming $0 \ln 0 = 0$. First term on the right is integrable, since $\int \ln^2(s) ds < \infty$, so it's martingale. Then the one that interests us is integrable as well.

This approach seems rather fishy, at best, and straight out wrong, at worst, but I don't have any better idea right now.

Second one:
$$ \mathbb{E} B_t \vert \mathcal{F}_s = B_s$$

$ \int_0^l B_s/s ds $ is $\mathcal{F}_l$-measurable. Then $\mathbb{E} \int_l^t B_s / s ds = \int_l^t \mathbb{E} B_s /s ds = 0$, so whole expression is martingale with quadratic variation equal to $t$, because second part is finite variation process, hence it's BM.

However, I have a feeling that it should be doable without invoking Levy's characterization. How?

So, my questions, as usual - is any of these close to being correct? If not, what is correct approach and where are the mistakes?

Comment: For the first part, can you assume that Brownian motion is Holder continuous?

Comment: yes, I can assume Holder continuity

Comment: does it go like this: $\int^{\epsilon}_0 \vert B_s \vert /s ds < \int C s^{\alpha} /s ds = C \int s^{\alpha - 1} ds = C \frac{1}{\alpha} s^{\alpha} \big\vert_0^{\epsilon}$ ?

Comment: That's what I had in mind yes!

Comment: thank you! any thoughts on my approach?

Comment: For the first part I think your approach makes sense, just depends whether you consider Holder continuity or the Ito formula + martingale properties as more or less elementary. I'm not sure I follow what you wrote for the 2nd part but I'm a little rusty.

Comment: The first part is trivial:$B_s \sim \sqrt s X$ where $X \sim N(0,1)$. Hence $\int_0^{1} E|\frac {B_s} {s} ds|=\int_0^{1} \frac  1{\sqrt s} ds E|X| <\infty$ which implies $\int_0^{1} |\frac {B_s} {s} ds|<\infty$ almost surely.

Comment: @KaboMurphy is it? don't we need integrability, which we are trying to prove, to put expected value inside integral?

Comment: @defenestrator No. Once you put absolute value for $B_s$ the integral makes sense and  we can use Tonelli's Theorem to interchange expectation and the integral.

Comment: I don't see why putting absolute value on $B_s$ makes integral well-defined - the part that has a potential for screwing up the integral is $1/s$, not the fact that $B_s$ can go either upwards or downwards.